# Wireless driver activation issue in Compaq c700 in Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux

I am using Ubuntu 9.04, I cant access my wireless driver, I activate the madwifi in administration>hardware drivers, but I could'nt activated the wireless too.

when I type lspci I get the following message,

```
################################################## #
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 04)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HEM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR242x 802.11abg Wireless PCI Express Adapter (rev 01)
02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
##################################################
```

but when I tried in Windows I found that the driver for my laptop is

```
################################################
atheros AR5007 802.11b/g WiFi Adapter
################################################
```

so what can I do for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789824) offers the following solution:

> First disable Atheros Hardware Access Layer [HAL]:
>   Go to System>Administration>Hardware Drivers
>   and uncheck Atheros Hardware Access Layer
>   then reboot
>
> after reboot type these into a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
wget http://snapshots.madwifi.org/special/madwifi-nr-r3366+ar5007.tar.gz
tar xfz madwifi-nr-r3366+ar5007.tar.gz
cd madwifi-nr-r3366+ar5007
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe ath_pci
```

> then reboot and it should work!

Note that these instructions are for Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy Heron. In 9.04, you *must connect to the internet* (usually via ethernet) *first* in order to setup proprietary wireless drivers. Ubuntu cannot distribute proprietary drivers with the install!

Answer (score 0):

i think you sholud use he ndiswrapper utility...

[Atheros AR5007 driver](http://www.atheros.cz/download.php?atheros=AR5007&system=3)

get the .inf file from above link,

use it using ndiswrapper, ENJOY :)